# Error while launching Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have zookeeper daemons running on the relevant nodes and am trying to launch a kafka broker but getting the following error:

```
FATAL [Kafka Server 13], Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2181""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ConnectStringParser.<init>(ConnectStringParser.java:72)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:443)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.<init>(ZooKeeper.java:380)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:64)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:876)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:98)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:84)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:157)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:82)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:29)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:46)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

My server.properties

```
broker.id=13
port=9092
host.name=node013
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
zookeeper.connect="node014:2181,node135:2181,node136:2181"
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

and zookeeper.properties

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
maxClientCnxns=0
```

I have tried but failed to figure out why the error logs are showing the extra " in the port property. Any idea what could be causing the issue ?

Comment: Remove useless double quotes for zookeeper.connect in server.properties

Comment: annoying that the example config has it quoted :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `server.properties` file, you need to remove the double quotes. 
It should be

```
zookeeper.connect=node014:2181,node135:2181,node136:2181
```

Answer (score -2):

The exception could be resolved by removing the space between the port stated "2181" and the command line option "--list".

> $ ./kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181  --list
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2181 "
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ConnectStringParser.(ConnectStringParser.java:72)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.(ZooKeeper.java:443)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.(ZooKeeper.java:380)
>       at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection.connect(ZkConnection.java:70)
>       at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1228)
>       at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.(ZkClient.java:157)
>       at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.(ZkClient.java:131)
>       at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:103)
>       at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.apply(ZkUtils.scala:85)
>       at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:58)
>       at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)